Divi Theme showing Original Image instead of the thumbnail
I am using Divi theme for one of my website, and in the recent blog section (sidebar) of the blog post the original image is getting loaded instead of the thumbnail.
Do i need to specifiy specifically about getting the thumbnail in the blog post section or Divi theme by default show the image thumbnails?
